# ¿A qué se debe la pérdida de 2 puntos de reputación por cada pregunta/respuesta eliminada que no son mías?

Tags: discusión, reputación

Me he encontrado con una situación un poco *rara*. Lo cierto, es que he perdido **2 puntos de reputación** por cada pregunta o respuesta eliminada **que no son mías (preguntas o respuestas ajenas)** (no estoy seguro de que sea por respuesta, creo más que sea por cada pregunta eliminada).

Lo cierto es que pierdo **2 puntos** cuando ocurre un evento, tal y como se ilustra en las siguientes imágenes:

[image: Vista previa]
[image: Vista previa]

Pero, tampoco se refleja ninguna notificación de que he perdido *dos puntos*; cosa que sí sucede cuando recibo votos *positivos/negativos* y/o me aceptan una respuesta.

La pregunta es, **¿a qué se debe?**

Comment: Me gustaría saber a qué se deben los votos negativos, ya que esto es una pregunta en la que estoy presentando una inquietud que me parece válida.

Comment: Los votos en meta solo indican si los usuarios les gusto o no tu post, o si estan de acuerdo o no con la petición.

Comment: Si, lo sé. Pero, entonces, ¿dónde puedo puedo preguntar?, porque esta pregunta fue mal recibida. La pregunta es por qué pierdo puntos por preguntas/respuestas que no son mías.

Comment: Aproveché de actualizar la pregunta porque se estaba mal interpretando lo que quería preguntar. Con preguntas o respuestas eliminadas me refería las que no son mías.

Comment: La reputación esta relacionada con tu actividad en el sitio por lo que si no son tus pregunta y/o respuestas entonces es raro que pierdas(o ganes reputación) ¿estas seguro que no son tus preguntas o no publicaste una respuesta?

Comment: Así es. No son preguntas mías. Estuve buscando y nada. De hecho, he revisado mis publicaciones y no tienen ese problema, de allí, lo raro del asunto.

Comment: ¿podrias compartir los enlaces de esos posts? Otra cosa que puede ser es que si tuviste varias cuentas y el sistema se entero entonces pudiste perder esos puntos al fusionarse los puntajes

Comment: Dale, los voy a recopilar y los compartiré

Comment: mmm, acabo de ver tu historial de reputación del 13 de febrero y solo veo los 10 puntos, no veo la pérdida de puntos

Comment: Tiene mucho sentido. No lo había pensado.

Comment: Eso nunca me ha pasado, pero tiene mucha lógica :-), si alguien puede ver los post podria indicar si tu editaste alguna publicación(pregunta o respuesta) y confirmar el hecho

Comment: Voy a buscar entre las ediciones aprobadas. Si encuentro compartiré el enlace.

Comment: Busqué en mi perfil donde aparecen todas las [sugerencias de ediciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/67242/david-e-luna-m?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=4) y las comparé con el [nombre de las preguntas o respuestas eliminadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/67242/david-e-luna-m?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=1&StartDate=2021-02-27%2001:25:46Z) y no encontré _ninguna coincidencia_. Pero esto no quiere decir que  lo que dice @BetaM no tenga sentido. Tiene mucha lógica. Lástima que no tengo suficiente reputación como para ver las preguntas / respuestas eliminadas.

Comment: Justo por ello te pedi que publiques los enlaces de los post eliminados para que otro usuario con el privilegio de ver post eliminados pueda averiguar(y/o confirmar) ello

Comment: Lástima que no los puedo ver.

Comment: ¿Pero no se puede copiar y pegar los enlaces?.

Comment: No se ve los votos negativos en tu historial.

Comment: Lamentablemente no aparece disponible porque las preguntas/respuestas que se habían eliminado no tiene un enlace que permita seguirlas. Para poder verlas tendría que tener una reputación de 10k en adelante.

Comment: se eliminaría alguna publicación en la que sugeriste una edición

Comment: Así es, y eso tiene mucho sentido. Lo malo fue que tuve escarbar hasta más no poder jejeje.

Comment: Después de leer, me encontré con **¿Qué más debería saber acerca de la eliminación?, y creo que la responde, al igual que la respuesta publicada más abajo en esta publicación. Pero, tuve que leer bastante.

Comment: Acabo de cerrar la pregunta porque considero que el enlace compartido por @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' responde la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La reputación que se gana con una pregunta o la respuesta a una pregunta se pierde cuando se elimina, **sí**.

Cuando elimine una pregunta, también recuperará la reputación que perdió con el voto negativo, pero no de inmediato, sino que la obtendrá cuando se active la siguiente recalculo.

Estos recálculos ocurren cada X tiempo, desconozco con exactitud el intervalo, pero esto se ve a menudo cuando un usuario se ensalza con otro, y hace una serie consecutiva de votos negativos a sus post, el sistema los detecta y los revertirá automáticamente eventualmente.

Por lo general, eso sucede en una hora.

Tenga en cuenta que la reputación perdida de Upvotes por preguntas eliminadas se conserva cuando la respuesta que dio tiene al menos 60 días de antigüedad y una puntuación de 3 o más.

Esta pregunta esta documentada en el sitio en ingles y por ende al compartir el mismo `engine` supongo y creo que comparten parámetros:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320459/why-are-reputation-points-lost-for-deleted-questions

[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

Incluso, si hay cambios en menos de 60 días también perderás la reputación ganada de ediciones si las preguntas son eliminadas.

Comment: Hola @Francisco, me refería a las preguntas o respuestas ajenas, aquellas que no son mías. Actualicé la pregunta para que se entendiera mejor.

Comment: aplica igual la norma

Comment: Si, me di cuenta. Era que las preguntas que había editado antes de alcanzar la reputación que actualmente tengo habían sido eliminadas y obviamente, la reputación que había ganado en esas ediciones aprobadas las perdí en las preguntas / respuestas que se eliminaron y que  previamente había editado.

Comment: correcto y esas preguntasno lle

Comment: correctoy esas preguntas no llegaron a los 60 dias.

Comment: Si quiere, edita la respuesta agregando esa información adicional para aceptarla. La idea es que si a otro usuario le sucede algo similar encuentre información útil acá.

Comment: listo, ya lo agregue